# How to force a refresh of Ajax data

Tags: tablesorter

I'm using the Ajax pager and I have some code that adds a record to my database. What I want to do is force the records to be refreshed. I'm trying to use $("builders_table").trigger("update"), but that doesn't work. If I change pages or filter the records, then the updated records are returned, but I would like to force a refresh as soon as the database is changed.

Thanks

```
$('#builders_table')
.tablesorter({
  theme: 'blue',
  widthFixed: true,
  cancelSelection: false,
  sortLocaleCompare: true, // needed for accented characters in the data
  sortList: [ [1,1] ],
  widgets: ['zebra', 'filter']
})

.tablesorterPager({

  container: $('.pager'),

  ajaxUrl : '/builder_data.php?page={page}&size={size}&{filterList:filter}&{sortList:column}',

  // use this option to manipulate and/or add additional parameters to the ajax url
  customAjaxUrl: function(table, url) {
      // manipulate the url string as you desire
      //url += url_extras;

      // trigger a custom event; if you want
      $(table).trigger('changingUrl', url);
      // send the server the current page
      return url;
  },
  ajaxError: null,
  ajaxObject: {
    dataType: 'json'
  },
  ajaxProcessing: function(data){
    if (data && data.hasOwnProperty('rows')) { 
         return [ data.total_rows, $(data.rows) ];
    } 
  }, 

  // Set this option to false if your table data is preloaded into the table, but you are still using ajax
  processAjaxOnInit: true,
  initialRows: {
    // these are both set to 100 in the ajaxProcessing
    // the these settings only show up initially
    total: 50,
    filtered: 50
  },
  output: '{startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})',
  updateArrows: true,
  page: 0,
  size: 50,
  savePages: false,
  storageKey: 'tablesorter-pager',
  pageReset: 0,
  fixedHeight: false,
  removeRows: false,
  countChildRows: false,

  // css class names of pager arrows
  cssNext        : '.next',  // next page arrow
  cssPrev        : '.prev',  // previous page arrow
  cssFirst       : '.first', // go to first page arrow
  cssLast        : '.last',  // go to last page arrow
  cssGoto        : '.gotoPage', // page select dropdown - select dropdown that set the "page" option

  cssPageDisplay : '.pagedisplay', // location of where the "output" is displayed
  cssPageSize    : '.pagesize', // page size selector - select dropdown that sets the "size" option

  // class added to arrows when at the extremes; see the "updateArrows" option
  // (i.e. prev/first arrows are "disabled" when on the first page)
  cssDisabled    : 'disabled', // Note there is no period "." in front of this class name
  cssErrorRow    : 'tablesorter-errorRow' // error information row

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The pager has a built-in method to force an update named ["pagerUpdate"](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pagerupdate):

You can force an update as follows:

```
$('table').trigger('pagerUpdate');
```

or, if you want to force an update and change the page

```
$('table').trigger('pagerUpdate', 3); // update and set to page 3
```

Comment: Thanks Mottie. I really appreciate the great support you give.